# Proving Beta prior distribution is conjugate to a negative binomial likelihood

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, beta-function

Show that the Beta prior is conjugate to a negative binomial likelihood, i.e., if $\mathbf{X} | \theta \sim \mathrm{NegBin}(k,\theta)$ and $\theta \sim \text{Beta}(a, b)$, then $\theta | \mathbf{X}  \sim \text{Beta}(a^\ast, b^\ast)$ for a pair of parameters $a^\ast, b^\ast > 0$.

Find an expression for $a^\ast$ and $b^\ast$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote the $n$ samples of $X$ as $x_1, \cdots, x_n$.

Note the following:

$$
\begin{align}
\pi (\theta | \mathbf{X}) &\propto \frac{ \Gamma(a + b) }{ \Gamma(a) \Gamma(b) } \theta^{a - 1} (1-\theta)^{b - 1} I_{(0 \le \theta \le 1)} \\
&\times \prod_i^n \left[ \frac{\Gamma(k + x_i)}{ \Gamma(k) \Gamma(x_i + 1) } \theta^{x_i}(1 - \theta)^k  \right] \\[10pt]
&\propto \theta^{a + \sum x_i - 1} (1 - \theta)^{b + nk - 1} I_{(0 \le \theta \le 1)}
\end{align}
$$

The last line has the form of **beta distribution** with the parameters $a^\ast = a + \sum x_i$, $b^\ast = b + nk$